# To find and print a matching word between two commas using either sed, grep or cut

Tags: linux, shell

I have a log and it has data like :

```
ProcessID='3940', Key='1', Number='5547', TotalNumberOfInputMessages='1', TotalElapsedTime='1332',
```

there are many other such info in log, but I am interested in particularly printing only `TotalNumberOfInputMessages='1'` occurrences ... There are many such occurrences in the log file with this value changing for `TotalNumberOfInputMessages`.

I want output like :

```
TotalNumberOfInputMessages='1'
TotalNumberOfInputMessages='diff value'
TotalNumberOfInputMessages='diff value'
TotalNumberOfInputMessages='diff value'
```

How can i achieve it by cut, sed or grep ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grep -Eo`:

```
grep -Eo "\bTotalNumberOfInputMessages='[^']*'" file
TotalNumberOfInputMessages='1'
```